# Связать телеграмм бота с сайтом php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Учусь делать ботов телеграм на php. Локально развернул композер, подключил библиотеку, и застопорился на связывании бота с сайтом, у меня при переходе по ссылке которую я получил - вываливается просто результат гуглопоиска, или я может что не так делаю?
Статья по которой все делаю [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/347482/)
Ссылка которую я получил
тык [ссылку](http://https:%20//api.telegram.org/bot%7E1120069036:AAHzWWTlShD4dJRZeGK2n7ISRbpZpKPZGOQ%7E/setWebhook?url=https://botted.pp.ua:9101/bot.php)

Comment: Если по простому, типа только пхп использовать, то создаешь форму на хтмл, в action ставишь имя обработчика. Далее в этом обработчике уже обрабатываешь полученные данные от формы и допустим отправляешь  их в ТГ

Comment: не совсем понял, то есть эта ссылка которая в статье - это адрес обработчика что ли? просто я не совсем могу понять какую роль там играет связывание с сайтом если можно сделать так как вы говорите?

Comment: Я статью не читал. Это я говорю как бы я сделал, если по простому

Comment: Прочитал статью. Тебе нужно купить vds или хост, где ты разместишь свой сайт. Далее подключаешь бота телеграмма к сайту, по той ссылке. А дальше все по инструкции. Таким образом ты сможешь получать команды от бота к себе на сервер. А то что я сказал, это лишь отправлять сообщения можно так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема до простого банальна, ссылка вставлялась с лишним пробелом, в адресной строке, соответственно я получал не JSON ответ а результат поиска гугла.